# How to serialize form inside modal window in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to build modal windows on the fly from single javascript object passed by server. 
But I have no clue how can I serialize form inside modal window without defining form variable .
In most examples serialize process look like this:

```
//create form
var CustomForm = new Ext.FormPanel({...});
//submiting form
CustomForm.getForm().submit({...});
```

In my case all inner components like "form" are created from xtype value,and no variable is assigned to it.
Is there any way to select and serialize form using something like this:

```
Ext.get(this).select('form').serialize();
```

or what is apropriate way of doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the form an id and use Ext.getCmp(formid).

To retrieve the form values of a FormPanel use `myFormPanel.getForm().getValues()`

That will come back with a js object representing the form fields.

Comment: Thanks it is working now, how ever is it possible to select parent form using pressed button as refference?

Comment: Use myButton.findParentByType('form')

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function to take values from a form and generate a string for adding to the query string:

```
/**
 * takes an array of form values and converts them into a
 * query string
 * 
 * @param {object} Ext.form
 * @return {string} 
 */
this.serialize_form_values = function(form)
{
    var serial = '',
        values = form.getValues();

    for(var value in values)
        serial += '&' + value + '=' + values[value];

    return serial.substr(1);
};
```

Maybe it could be useful for someone?